# Bootstrap select text is not centered with some fonts - causing some characters to be partially hidden

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Using this font [Google Font Cairo](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Cairo) with the **select** text make the inner text partially hidden, like if it's shifted down a little bit. The issue doesn't exist when removing bootstrap.

Tried different versions of Bootstrap 4.

JSFiddle example https://jsfiddle.net/pgmx87jv/17/

```
<select class="form-control"  style="font-family: 'Cairo', sans-serif;">
  <option>Village</option>
  <option>ggg</option>
  <option>Vvv</option>
</select>
```

Why does it happen and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the padding on the select `form-control`. It's happening because the Cairo font is taller than Bootstrap's default font.

```
<select class="form-control pt-0">
  <option>Village</option>
  <option>ggg</option>
  <option>Vvv</option>
</select>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/m1d5oayu/

***Or,*** use the `h-auto` class to set `height:auto` as suggested by @IvanS95...

```
<select class="form-control h-auto">
  <option>Village</option>
  <option>ggg</option>
  <option>Vvv</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Either that or setting the `.form-control`'s height to `auto` also solves the issue